# How to open .ashx file with Samsung Galaxy Mini 3

Tags: pdf, samsung-mobile, ashx

Using my PC the files are opened as .pdf, but if i try the same with my Samsung Galaxy Mini i get an error message: **ashx - not supported format** Do i need to install extra software to view the files?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

.ashx file is an ASP.NET web forms file for delivering a dynamic content, which means the final file could contain the PDF content in it. so just rename this file to .pdf and it should work (hopefully).

Comment: I have a friend with an Iphone.He can open the file without any problem.The result is a .pdf file and he is not getting the error message: ashx not supported

Comment: Open it with a hex editor or even a simple text editor and see if its content starts with `%PDF` or not. If not, it's not a PDF file.

Comment: On my PC and my friends IPhone it opens as a PDF file.